# how to access <select> tag's id in c# using asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using a  tag to get values from the textboxes and show them in a drop down. see the image below:[image: preview of running app]

now the problem is that select tag's id is not accessing in C#/code behind asp page.
i have tried to use Request.Form.GetValues("correct")

"correct" is the id of select tag.
but still i'm not able to access the text that has been selected by the user.
Thanks in advance and pardon me if my formating was not ok.

Comment: use `name` attribute instead of `id`

Comment: Add `markup` of select tag in the question to make it more clear.

Comment: <select id="correct" name="correctname" onfocus="loadOptions()" style="width: 20%;" runat="server"></select>

Comment: Why can't you add `runat="server"` to the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your markup is right, and `select` tag has `id="correct" name="correct"` this should work:

```
<select id="correct" name="correct">

string sValue = Request.Form["correct"];
```

For multiple values you can use:

```
string[] arrValues = Request.Form.GetValues("correct");

foreach(string sVal in arrValues)
{
     //sVal is required string
}
```

**Note**: you can also get value:

```
string sCorrectVal = correct.Value;
```

Comment: by using string[] arrValues i get string[1]=op1 (checked while debugging)..now how can i get this values into simple string? thanks though

Comment: You can loop through all values. I have updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have the selected city value on postback:

```
string correct= Request.Form.Get("correct");
```

Comment: i have already tried this. it gives me error "cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string" so i used var correct=Request.Form.Get("correct"); instead of string but now i am not able to get text from correct

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat="server"` attribute to the `select` tag like this:

```
<select id="correct" runat="server">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

which will make `correct` a [HtmlSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/807bc327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), then get the selected value in your code behind like this:

```
correct.Value
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a bit but i am getting null value in correct.value

Comment: See my edited answer, do you have `<option>` tags inside the `<select>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the html **name** of the element to reference it in the `Request` object.  If there is no name, add one:

```
<select name="correct" >
```

For more information, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I have given name but still it is not accessable